# BTSTask RemoveApp Gives Object Reference Error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, btstask

I have a BizTalk 2013r2 app with a receive location that uses the codeplex scheduled task adapter with a custom task.

If I try to remove the app using "BTSTask RemoveApp -ApplicationName:MyApp" from an admin elevated command line window, then I get the following error:

> Error: Error while removing application "MyApp".
>   Error: Could not validate TransportTypeData, Address or Public Address properties for Receive Location 'SharePoint.Sport
>   sTimetable.Receive.SiteTimetable-Schedule'. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

However, if I right-click the app in the BizTalk admin console and select Delete then it gets deleted no problem.

Any ideas how to fix this - there are no clues in the event log?

Answer (score 0):

I switched from BTSTask to BTS Powershell, that's maybe a (workaround) solution?
https://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/

Comment: The BizTalk PowerShell plugin is great but I'm working with the BizTalk Deployment Framework which uses BTSTask.exe. I can work around this problem but I'm curious to know if anyone else has hit the same.